# Excluding a file from coverage report in lcov

Tags: c, gcc, gcov, lcov

I tried to remove coverage data on my test driver file "test.c". Below is what I was using after reading some similar questions in SO.

```
$ lcov --remove test.gcda -c -d . -o a.info --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1
```

but I got an error below. Can anyone help?

```
lcov: ERROR: only one of -z, -c, -a, -e, -r, -l, --diff or --summary allowed!
Use lcov --help to get usage information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-r` is the same as `--remove`. And the error message says that you cannot use `-r` and `-c` at the same time. Remove the `-c` parameter.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. I figured out lcov --remove operates on .info files instead of .gcda files.